# How do I get this radio on and off to work with the python file below

Tags: python, html, raspbian

webpage HTML code

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/lights.py" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="lighton" value="on">On<br>
<input type="radio" name="lightoff" value="off">Off
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">  
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Python code that I want to turn the light on with is just need to figure out how to add them to the file below:

```
pl = pilight.PILIGHT()
pl.createPiLight(255,255,255)
```

Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb
import time
import os, sys
import pilight
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
form=cgi.FieldStorage()

if "light" not in form:
    print "<h1>Neither radio button was selected.</h1>"
else:
    text=form["light"].value
    print "<h1>Radio button chosen:</h1>"
    print cgi.escape(text)
    print "Check that Pi-Light is working correctly"
```

ON Condition:

```
pl = pilight.PILIGHT()
pl.createPiLight(255,255,255)
```

OFF Condition:

```
pl = pilight.PILIGHT()
pl.createPiLight(000,000,000)
```